# How to connect mssql in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect codeigniter with MSSQL. I have done all possible changes in the `php.ini` file by adding the extensions `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`. But still am facing sqlsrv error as follow,

> *Error: Message: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given*

**sqlsrv_driver.php**

```
function _execute($sql)
{
    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    return sqlsrv_query($this->conn_id, $sql, null, array(
        'Scrollable'                => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC,
        'SendStreamParamsAtExec'    => true
    ));
}
```

`$this->conn_id` --- this is empty. I don't know why its getting null value.

**Codeigniter Version : 2.2 /**
**PHP Version : 5.6**

**Database configuration :**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '.\sqlexpress';
$db['default']['username'] = 'UNAME';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DBNAME'; 
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

NOTE: I have been stuck in this for past 3 day and  i have tried . Since i am new to MSSQL, i cant able to figure out the problem. Any help in this would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please show how you define and populate `$this->conn_id`. Either you aren't assigning a value to this, or it's null because your database connection code failed. It's that code which is important for your problem, not the code which executes specific queries.

Comment: what version of mssql native client are you using?

Comment: P.S. what operating system are you running PHP under? the sqlsrv driver only works on Windows. If your PHP is running on Linux/Mac you'll need to use ODBC.

Comment: @Ashishrawat 2017

Comment: @ADyson you are right. After enabling db_debug to TRUE am getting error "Unable to connect to databas". I am using windows and XAMPP

Comment: Hopefully your error message is more detailed than that?? please show the relevant code and the full error details.

Comment: P.S. you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php . This would also give you access to newer versions of the sqlsrv drivers.

Comment: This might be important because I suspect your drivers cannot connect to newer versions of SQL Server. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Per the "PHP Version Support" table in that guide, on PHP version 5.6 you can only run version 3.2 of the sqlsrv drivers. And per the table above that, version 3.2 of the drivers only supports SQL 2014 and below, but you've stated you're using SQL 2017.

Comment: Okay, i will try to do the same with 2014 and let you know

Comment: surely it would be better to upgrade to a supported PHP version than to downgrade your SQL server

Comment: you are right, i am planning to do the upgrade.

Comment: by the mean time i will try to configure with 2014 .

Comment: ```$db['my_mssql']['hostname'] = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client version here};Server=Host\Instance;Database=queue_sys;';$db['my_mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';``` make these changes in databse.php and try

Comment: @ADyson I have downgraded my sql server to 2008, but still i am having the same issue.'Unable to connect to the database server''

Comment: @Ashishrawat Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running an unsupported version of PHP. You need to upgrade your PHP version to continue to receive security updates. See https://php.net/supported-versions.php.

Doing this would also give you access to newer versions of the sqlsrv drivers. This is important because your current driver cannot connect to newer versions of SQL Server.

You've stated you're using SQL 2017. However as per the [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15), with PHP version 5.6 you can only run version 3.2 of the sqlsrv drivers, and version 3.2 of the drivers only supports SQL 2014 and below.

Comment: I have downgraded my sql server to 2008, but still i am having the same issue.'Unable to connect to the database server''.

Comment: Well that could be due to any number of factors, e.g. wrong connection string, network problems, SQL not running, authentication issues. Does your application have an error log file? Maybe a more detailed error message would be logged in there.

Comment: P.S. SQL 2008 is past the end of its overall support period (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4456242/end-of-support-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2), it's not a good idea to run that versin. Use 2012 or 2014 for your purpose.